# Joomla admin componet redirect is not working?

Tags: redirect, joomla, components, admin

I need to create a redirect with message in  admin joomla component, I'm using joomla 2.5
and without MVC pattern.

This is my code

```
global $mainframe;    
$mainframe->redirect('index.php?option=com_book','Message Saved');
```

But it's generating a fatal Error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function redirect() on a non-object in
```

Please help me out guys, you guys may be expert in joomla component devopment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because Joomla! 2.5 doesn't have a global `$mainframe` object, that is a hangover from Joomla 1.0 days. In Joomla! 1.5 it was a *legacy* support feature.

You can use the the following to replace *your* `$mainframe`:

```
$jApp = JFactory::getApplication();
$jApp->redirect($url, $msg);
```

If you're updating old code to work with Joomla! 2.5 you should read [this article](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6) which covers these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Fast way

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();    
$mainframe->redirect('index.php?option=com_book','Message Saved');
```

Comment: $mainframe in only a variable here. It's not the issue.